# Having a group $G$ and $x,y\in{G}$. If we know that $x^g=y^g$, is always true that $x=y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've got a doubt about a problem I've solved:

I've got a group $G$ and $x,y\in{G}$. If we know that $x^g=y^g$, is alwaystrue that $x=y$?

---

What I've done is:

$x^g=y^g\iff g^{-1}xg=g^{-1}yg\iff xg=yg\iff x=y$ , $\forall x,y \in G$

So my answer is that it is always true. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I don't think I know what your notation $x^g$ means.

Comment: In the question doesn't specify anything. My doubt is if I have to do as I have done or as a symple power of numbers..

Comment: @B.Goddard: $x^g=g^{-1}xg$. This is fairly standard and can in any case be inferred from the calculation following *What I’ve done is:*.

Comment: @User160: I think it very likely that $g$ is intended to represent an element of the group, not an integer, so I expect that you’ve done exactly what was wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your answer is correct, you could also approach the problem as follows:

Let $g \in G$. Then $f_{g}: G \rightarrow G$ defined by $f_{g}(x) = gxg^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism: $f_{g}(xy) = g(xy)g^{-1} = (gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})= f_{g}(x)\cdot f_{g}(y)$ and $\ker f_{g} = \{1_{G}\}$ so that $f_{g}$ is one-to-one and the result follows.